# Newtonian Mechanics - Regarding Conservation of Momentum in Collisions

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision, string

[image: Sorry for the crude diagram]

In the question, it is given that all three balls are identical and are connected by a massless, ideal string (on a horizontal plane), and initially, the ball at the centre is given a velocity $v$. If momentum is conserved along $y$ axis, then the velocities of the balls are $v/3$ (along the $y$ axis, when the balls at the extremities collide). My question is, that why won't the balls have different velocities after conserving momentum along the $y$ axis?

Comment: General tip: Put keywords in tagline rather than title. Use title for main question.

Comment: How are you applying momentum conservation here exactly?